# Python uses incorrect OpenSSL version

Tags: python, windows, openssl

I uninstalled OpenSSL from my Windows PC, in fact when i launch `openssl --version`

I received error message `command not found`

but when I launch python command

```
python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```

I get
`OpenSSL 1.1.1u  30 May 2023`

If I install latest version of OpenSSL (v.3.1.2), I always get v.1.1.1u version with python command

I want to remove 1.1.1 version and install v3.1.2; to get v3.1.2 with command

```
python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```

My python version is 3.11.4